# CustomTicks - Changing NumberPoint -> ","

Tags: plotting, formatting

How can I change the number point from `.` to `,` in `CustomTicks` ? 
The *Mathematica* built-in function

```
NumberForm[Plot[…],NumberPoint -> ","]
```

doesn't work any more, if you use e.g. `LinTicks`.

Comment: Hi, you can manage `Ticks` in ways that are described [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33297/5478) or in the related topics that are linked in this question.

Answer (score 7):

**Update**

Here is a better way.  `FixedPointForm` is used to format the tick numbers.  Its default options include `NumberPoint -> "."`:

```
Options[FixedPointForm]
(* {NumberSigns -> {"-", ""}, NumberPoint -> ".", SignPadding -> False, Debug -> False} *)
```

Reset the `NumberPoint` option as desired:

```
SetOptions[FixedPointForm, NumberPoint -> ","];
Plot[E^x Sin[10 x], {x, -1, 1}, Ticks -> LinTicks]
```

---

**Original**

The question, [CustomTicks and small ranges](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4092/customticks-and-small-ranges), shows one can pass a formatting function to `LinTicks`:

```
Plot[E^x Sin[10 x], {x, -1, 1}, 
 Ticks ->
   (LinTicks[##, TickLabelFunction -> (NumberForm[#, {2, 1}, NumberPoint -> ","] &)] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*[A weakness in the original solution is having to set the number form explicitly instead of automatically.]*

Answer (score 6):

Unless the number point is explicit in this tick package can't you just use `Style` to override the global setting? e.g

[image]

and

```
Style[
 Plot[E^x Sin[10 x], {x, -1, 1}],
 NumberPoint -> "CC"]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, +1, I didn't know that `NumberPoint` is option for `Style`. But since it is you can also use `BaseStyle -> {NumberPoint -> ","}`